# If the inner product of two vectors is constant along a curve, then both vectors are parallel transported along the curve

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

Given the vectors $A$ and $B$, and a curve with a tangent vector $U$, I need to show that if $\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left(g_{\mu\nu}A^\mu B^\nu \right)=0$, then $ U^\alpha\nabla_\alpha A^\mu=0 $ and $ U^\alpha\nabla_\alpha B^\mu=0 $.

I've done this going in the other direction, but going in this direction is giving me trouble. I've gotten to the equation
$$ -g_{\mu\nu}B^\nu U^\alpha \nabla_\alpha A^\mu=g_{\mu\nu}A^\mu U^\alpha \nabla_\alpha B^\nu $$
But I can't see where to go from here. When I emailed my professor, all he said that because $g_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric, then that means both sides of my equation are the same, but one has a minus sign, which leads to both sides being $0$. I'm not seeing how the metric being symmetric leads to both sides of the equation being identical, as on one side the derivative is on $A$ and on the other it is on $B$. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why should this be true? In basic calculus, if the product of two functions is constant, can we conclude the functions are constant? Take two orthogonal vector fields of varying lengths here. The inner product is $0$ and neither vector field is parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trivial counter-example: on $\Bbb R$, let $A(t) = 0$ and $B(t) = t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. Then $\langle A,B\rangle =0$ even though $B$ is not parallel.

Non trivial counter-example: consider $\Bbb R^2$ with its euclidean structure, and $\gamma(t) = (t,0)$, which is a geodesic. Let $A(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ and $B(t) = (-\sin t, \cos t)$ be tangent vectors along $\gamma$. Then $\langle A, B\rangle = 0$ even though neither $A$ nor $B$ is parallel.